# GoogleMap api - ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, reference

I'm struggling with **Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment**.
I adapted a Wordpress template that contains a function to add a map on certain page.
This is the function and the error is on this row

```
script.src == 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&'+'callback=base_hotel_initialize'&key=*MYAPI*;
```

Obviously I user a valid API and I tried bot with one or 2 equal (the original was with one)

```
<script>
'use strict';
function base_hotel_initialize() {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-30.50,115.85);
var myOptions = {
zoom: 12,
center: latlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
scrollwheel: false
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemap'), myOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latlng, 
map: map,
icon: "***/wp-content/themes/base-hotel/images/point.png"
});
}
function base_hotel_loadscript() {
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src == 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&'+'callback=base_hotel_initialize'&key=*MYAPI*;
document.body.appendChild(script);
}
window.onload = base_hotel_loadscript;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the full context of your code to assist you more but fixed version of the line you mentioned is

```
script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=base_hotel_initialize&key='+MYAPI;
```

Comment: This is the original code (not working) that I'm trying to debug.

Comment: @domfitty It's not the original code. There's a syntax error in your code.